# Why $||f||=\mathrm{sup}_{||g||=1}|\langle{f,g}\rangle|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

My question is why $||f||=\mathrm{sup}_{||g||=1}|\langle{f,g}\rangle|$? for any two functions $f$ and $g$ with $||g||=1$, and $||\;||$ denotes the 2-norm.

I have tried to use the triangle inequality but only got  the $||f||\geq \mathrm{sup}_{||g||=1}|\langle{f,g}\rangle| $ side, what about the other side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
The Cauchy Schwarz inequality states that 
$$
|\langle f,g \rangle|\leq\|f\|\cdot \|g\|
$$
For the other direction, it suffices to show that there exists a vector $g$ with $\|g\| = 1$ such that $|\langle f,g \rangle| = \|f\|$.  In particular, we may take
$$
g = \frac{f}{\|f\|}
$$
Note that for this $g$, we have
$$
\left\langle g,f
\right\rangle = 
\left\langle \frac{f}{\|f\|},f
\right\rangle = 
\frac{1}{\|f\|}
\left\langle f,f
\right\rangle = 
\frac{1}{\|f\|}\|f\|^2 = \|f\|
$$
Because $|\langle f,g \rangle| = \|f\|$ for this particular $g$, we conclude $\sup_{g:\|g\|=1} |\langle f,g \rangle| \geq \|f\|$.

Comment: Yeah that's how I got $||f||\geq \mathrm{sup}_{||g||=1}|\langle{f,g}\rangle| $. Now I wanna the other direction. Sorry for the typo in the OP, it's I got $||f||\geq \mathrm{sup}_{||g||=1}|\langle{f,g}\rangle| $, but not $||f||\leq \mathrm{sup}_{||g||=1}|\langle{f,g}\rangle| $. I've edited it. How about the other side?

Comment: Why $\langle g,f \rangle = \|f\|$?

Comment: See my latest edit.

Answer (score 3):

Choose $g={f \over \|f\|}$. Then $\|g\| =1$ and $\langle g,f \rangle = \|f\|$.

Comment: I am confused why $\langle g,f \rangle = \|f\|$? Thanks.

Comment: Because $\langle f , f \rangle = \|f\|^2$, and $\langle g , f \rangle = \langle {f \over \|f\|}  , f \rangle = \|f\|$.